# How to use if condition to validate that the new values that is being updated is same as the values provided from the data table

Tags: java

I am updating old value with the new value(values are provided from data table).I have written code to validate both the attributes are not equal.So now I am looking for validating the new values with values I am passing from the data table to be same(CSV file).

Comment: by writing code that verifies that, how else? if ( value.equals(expectedValue)) System.out.println("ok"); else System.out.println("error");

Answer (score 0):

```
/**1，get the obj/dbvalue by your own searchObjectfromDB(),2 compare the input value with dbvalue */
Object obj = searchObjectfromDB(id);
if(request.getValue().eQueals(Object.getValue()));
```

Comment: this contains way to little context to be a good answer. You'll have to add more explanation

Comment: OKay,let me add

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.